# In the Shabbos morning prayers, the refrain of "shochain od" is said. Why is it said in a different order than the verse (Isaiah 57:15) itself?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat

"...כִּי֩ כֹ֨ה אָמַ֜ר רָ֣ם וְנִשָּׂ֗א שֹׁכֵ֥ן עַד֙ וְקָד֣וֹשׁ שְׁמ֔וֹ מָר֥וֹם וְקָד֖וֹשׁ אֶשְׁכּ֑וֹן" is how the verse reads. Most siddurim read שׁוכֵן עַד       מָרום וְקָדושׁ שְׁמו, yet attribute the refrain to this verse in Isaiah. Is the refrain only "based" on the verse or was the switch for some other reason? I've seen the custom of the GR"A was to say the refrain following the order of the verse.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I assume that other nusachim have tradition that this part of Nishmat Kol Chai should be written this way. As for why it was written so, it's not uncommon for liturgy to borrow phrases from verses and change them a bit for poetic reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome and reply.

Comment: Where did you hear the Gra changed the wording? I've never heard that

Comment: Peerush Iyun tfillah in the bottom of the Siddur Otzer Hatfillos brings this nusach of the GR"A

Comment: Out of order is the wrong descriptor, in the sense that מרום וקדוש doesn't refer to שמו in the verse. The question is rather why מרום was added to the previous phrase when it was used for our prayers.

Comment: Perhaps מרום is supposed to be read forward and back, ie. שוכן עד is מרום, and שמו is מרום וקדוש.

Comment: I believe the Siddur Otzar HaTefillot is not saying what you think it's saying. It's saying that the Gra's girsa of Sefer Yetzira has שוכן עד וקדוש שמו מרום וקדוש הוא, and says nothing about the Gra's nusaḥ hatefilla. Indeed, none of the "Gra siddurim" out there these days (AFAIK) have a variant here. The usual printed text of Sefer Yetzira (eg on Sefaria) does have רם ונשא שוכן עד מרום וקדוש שמו. (ping @DoubleAA as well)

Comment: Thank you for your take on this. I too couldn't find it in any modern GR"A siddur.